# What framework does forkdelta use for its frontend?

Tags: frameworks, ethereum, solidity, dex, web3js

forkdelta URL:https://forkdelta.app

forkdelta github:https://github.com/forkdelta/classic-frontend

I checked forkdelta github page, but I can't understand forkdelta's frontend framework.

Is it Vue, or React or original html?

Please tell me forkdelta's frontend framework.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the Github page says, ForkDelta is not open source, as the unminified JavaScript files are missing from the Github repository.

It is not possible to tell and answer your question. Please contact ForkDelta team direclty.

Comment: I will contact ForkDelta team directly.